# Express router.use not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I used express-generator to generate the basic structure of an express app.

I have this in routes/my.js:

```js
 router.use('/update', function(req, res, next) {
    req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
    console.log('router use invoked');
    next();
 });

router.get('/update', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('=== GET /my/update', req.body);
});

router.post('/update', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('=== POST /my/update', req.body);
});
```

And in app.js I added:

```js
var my = require('./routes/my');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/my', my);
```

It's working fine for GET, and the router middle-ware is actually working (console.log is called), but the headers is not being set to app/json (as the log message in post outputs the body to be empty).

I can solve this by adding this **before any other middle-ware**

```js
app.use('/my/update', function(req, res, next) {
  req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
  next()
});
```

And it works. I tried moving the `app.use('my', my);` line before any other middle-ware but it stopped working altogether.

What can I do in order to give priority to my router.use?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the header to the `request` object, not the response. Also the below is the preferred way to do it.

```
router.use('/update', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('content-type', 'application/json');
    console.log('router use invoked');
    next();
});
```

Comment: I know I'm setting the request header, and it's what I want. I want to set a default content type for request.

Comment: You can't set the request header, only get. If you want to set a header, you have to do it on the response object. Request is incoming, response is outgoing.

Comment: Afaik I can, middle-wares are invoked before the request data is received. And like I said, it worked with app.use, just not with router.use.

Answer (score 0):

ExpressJS is all about working with middle wares.

According to official documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html), Middleware is a function with access to the request object (**req**), the response object (**res**), and the next middleware in line in the request-response cycle of an Express application, commonly denoted by a variable named next.

Middleware can:

- Execute any code
- Make changes to the request and the response objects
- End the request-response cycle
- Call the next middleware in the stack

I would like to point a few things about your **my.js** router, if you don't want to send any response back then it should be something like :

```
router.get('/update', function(req, res, next) {
    res.end();
});

router.post('/update', function(req, res, next) {
    res.end();
});
```

You must end your request, response cycle else it will be left hanging. Practically you would like to send some data(preferably JSON data) back to client so you can use [res.json()](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.json) or [res.send()](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send). You don't need to set application/json headers if you use res.json().

Comment: This has nothing to do with my problem. I already have res.end(), it was removed for the sake of simplicity. Again, my problem is about middle-ware's order

Comment: In short if you want to send JSON, you don't need any headers just use res.json() it works perfectly.

Comment: @AlexFerg Then you need to set the headers on whatever you're using to send the data. Doing it server-side makes no sense.

Comment: It does, it's some type of a fallback in case the sender didn't specify. Again, you didn't touch the problem, you're providing methods and solutions to a problem that doesn't exist.